# PHP array_key_exists and UTF 8

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database where encoding is UTF-8 for multilingual purpose.
I this that everything in my app is in UTF-8.

Though I have a problem with the array_key_exists function.

1. It starts by a query to the database

`SELECT name, value from TABLE`

1. Then I fill a hash map with the result :

`$hashmap[ $row['name'] ] = $row['value']`

But when the name in the DB contains accents like 'é', the following returns false :

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->select('value');
$this->db->from('table');
$q = $this->db->get();
$res = $q->result_array();

    foreach ($res as $value) {
        $hashmap[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
    }

$key = 'name é'; // an ord here returns 233
array_key_exists($key, $hashmap)
```

I dont know how to go further with that, did you encountered the problem ?

I have a performance requirement.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried it myself and it worked. Can you var_dump your resulted array `$hashmap` to check that `namé` is really in its keys?

Comment: If the `é` has an `ord` value of 233, that's not UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array key is encoded in UTF-8 if it indeed comes as UTF-8 string from the database. Apparently your *source code file* is not encoded in UTF-8, I'd guess it's encoded in Latin-1. A comparison between a UTF-8 byte sequence and a Latin-1 byte sequence is therefore unsuccessful. Save you source code files in UTF-8 and it should work (consult your text editor).

Comment: Thx but that's not a good way, all my files are in UTF-8, configured in eclipse.

Comment: Then it should work. Show me a `bin2hex` on both strings then, please.

Comment: Of course I show it to you : $name is the searched value "bin2hex($name)" (string:36) 4e6f6d6272652073616e732064e966617574 // "$name" (string:18) Nombre sans d�faut // And that one is the key in the array : "bin2hex($key)" (string:38) 4e6f6d6272652073616e732064c3a966617574 // "$key" (string:18) Nombre sans défaut

Comment: There you go. The latter string, where the é is c3a9, is UTF-8. The former, where the é is e9, is Latin-1.

Comment: Mmmh Ok I'll get that but I thought e9 was UTF-8 !! THANKS

Comment: You may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). :)

Comment: (I but back the comment then). You're true I was wrong. I was looking in the wrong column in that page : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

> But when the name in the DB contains accents like 'é', the following returns false : array_key_exists('namé', $hashmap)

Alas, up till now, string in PHP aren't UTF-8 encoded. I believe you'll have to encode them yourself:

```
<?php
array_key_exists(utf8_encode('namé'), $hashmap);
```

Comment: Actually the $key string is returned from the database. This one is for sure in UTF-8 because when i Ord() the char, I get 233. But I will check the code when I build the map.

Comment: PHP strings are byte arrays. They don't have any encoding per se. If the source string is UTF-8, the string is UTF-8. If it's not, it's not. `utf8_encode` *converts* a Latin-1 encoded string into a UTF-8 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php
$foo = array('namé' => 1);
var_dump($foo);
var_dump(array_key_exists('namé', $foo));
var_dump(isset($foo['namé']));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["namé"]=>
  int(1)
}
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

PHP version:

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2011 11:17:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

It seems to work okay for me in PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

@Berry

Indeed, when I build the hashmap, debugging I get this :

```
 $res = getDATABASEVALUES();
 //res contains 20 rows, the number 11 has accent
 $res[11]['name'] => returns 'name é'
 ord($res[11]['name'][5]) => returns 195 and not 233
```

Comment: The "e acute" character is encoded on two bytes in UTF-8, 0xC3 0xA9, so `ord(5)` should return 195 and `ord(6)` should return 169. Keep in mind that PHP strings are just a series of bytes, functions such as `ord()` and `strlen()` are not designed to "understand" UTF-8, they only work on bytes. See deceze's answers and comments, they are correct.