# php array elements UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, fpdf

I have a pdf form that I want to fill out with php. The pdf is read only so I cannot change the field names. The names of form fields are in UTF-8.

For example, I have a field with the name "Telefonska številka" which means telephone number. My php script returns that it cannot find the field with that name. I'm also working with characters š,č,ž (slovene language).

Is there any way to get around this problem?

I am using the FPDF library and the code looks something like this:

```
$fields = array(
'Telefonska številka'  =>  '040123456'
);
```

Comment: Is that source code saved in UTF-8…? Otherwise `"številka"` won't be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Take a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835964/php-array-key-exists-and-utf-8

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the fpdm library. I get the error "FPDF-Merge Error: field Telefonska številka not found"